# group “weighted” rolling mean while excluding own group value when a group has multiple observations

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to calculate group “weighted” rolling mean while excluding own group value when a group has multiple observations. This is related to my earlier question [group "weighted" mean with multiple grouping variables and excluding own group value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59818355/group-weighted-mean-with-multiple-grouping-variables-and-excluding-own-group-v). The key difference is that this method is not readily applicable since now a group has multiple observations.

Based on the following dataset, here's the operation I want to apply. For instance, the new variable for the first two rows will take 19*9/18 + 48*3/18 + 6*2/18 + 31*4/18 = 25.05. The next two rows will take  81*1/10 + 52*3/10 + 6*2/10 + 31*4/10 = 37.3, and so on.

```
set.seed(57)
df <- data.frame(
  state = rep(c("AL", "CA"), each = 12),
  year = rep(c(2011:2012), 12),
  county = rep(letters[1:6], each = 4),
  value = sample(100, 24),
  wt = sample(10, 24, replace = T)
) %>% arrange(state, year)
```

If I apply the following code, the issue is that observation from the same county is also included in the weighted mean formula.

```
df %>%
  group_by(state, year) %>%
  mutate(new_val = purrr::map_dbl(row_number(), 
                         ~weighted.mean(value[-.x], wt[-.x])))
```

As a get around, I've tried the following (find weighted mean within a county-year first and apply the code above), but the two are not producing the same results, tho somewhat similar.

```
df %>%
  group_by(state, county, year) %>%
  mutate(wp = weighted.mean(value, wt),
         wt2 = sum(wt)) %>%
  distinct(state, year, county, wp, wt2) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(state, year) %>%
  mutate(new_val = purrr::map_dbl(row_number(), 
                                  ~weighted.mean(wp[-.x], wt2[-.x])))
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this!

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, but I'm sure that this is not the best approach. Any other suggestions would be very helpful for future reference.

```
x <- c(rep(c(letters[1:3]), 2), rep(c(letters[4:6]), 2))
year <- rep(rep(c(2011:2012), each = 3), time = 2)
state <- rep(c("AL", "CA"), each = 6)

get_wv <- function(x, year, state){

  new_val <- weighted.mean(df$value[df$county != x & df$year == year & df$state == state], 
                                   df$wt[df$county != x & df$year == year & df$state == state])  

  new_val

}

res <- pmap(.l = list(x, year, state), .f = get_wv)
```