# How can I calculate a group-level statistic omitting a given sub-group nested within the group?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have long data that is students nested within classrooms. I would like to calculate various class-level statistics for each student about the classroom that they study in, but exclude the student's own data in this calculation.

A simple example would be as below:

```
 df <- data.frame(
  class_id = c(rep("a", 6), rep("b", 6)),
  student_id = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 2), rep(3, 1), rep(4, 2), rep(5, 3), rep(6, 1)),
  value = rnorm(12)
)
```

As shown above, I six students in two classrooms, each of which has one or more observations of value. It's easy to get the student-level average with:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(class_id, student_id) %>% 
  summarize(value = mean(value))
```

or to add a classroom-level average with:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(class_id) %>% 
  mutate(class_avg = mean(value))
```

but I can't figure out how to tell dplyr to "leave out" a given group in the higher-level group level calculation. This is similar to the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36450278/summarize-with-dplyr-other-then-groups), but that calculates the mean of all groups except for the given group. I'm not sure how to modify this with dplyr to get what I want.

Thanks for your help.

**Edit**: After @akrun's request, the expected output is below (using a slightly modified version of @jared_mamrot's answer). As you can see, the class_mean_othstudents variable takes the value of the mean of the students in each class *except for* the given student. Jared's solution works but is a very manual approach and would only apply to getting a mean value. I am wondering if there is a dplyr way to do this more generally.

```
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  class_id = c(rep("a", 6), rep("b", 6)),
  student_id = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 2), rep(3, 1), rep(4, 2), rep(5, 3), rep(6, 1)),
  value = rnorm(12)
)

df %>% 
  group_by(class_id, student_id) %>%
  summarize(student_mean = mean(value)) %>% 
  mutate(class_mean_othstudents = 
           (sum(student_mean) - student_mean)/(n() - 1)
  )

`summarise()` has grouped output by 'class_id'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   class_id [2]
  class_id student_id student_mean class_mean_othstudents
  <chr>         <dbl>        <dbl>                  <dbl>
1 a                 1       0.256                  0.907 
2 a                 2       0.0999                 0.986 
3 a                 3       1.72                   0.178 
4 b                 4      -0.402                  0.195 
5 b                 5       0.0305                -0.0211
6 b                 6       0.360                 -0.186
```

Comment: I am confused about how you want to compute `class_avg`.  Your sample code `df %>% group_by(class_id) %>% mutate(class_avg = mean(value))` returns the *overall mean* of all samples within a class but the accepted answer as well as the expected result use the *mean of means*. *Overall mean* and *mean of means* are different as explained [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/133138/113809), e.g. So, please, let us know what definition you prefer. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Uwe, this is a good point for clarification. I could see some use cases where you would want the overall mean (it would allow you to weight students with more observed data more heavily), but for me, I was definitely more interested in the means of students, and hence the means of means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the update, we may loop over the `row_number()`, get the 'student_mean' values that are not from the current row, get the `mean`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
  group_by(class_id, student_id) %>%
  summarize(student_mean = mean(value), .groups = 'drop_last') %>% 
  mutate(class_mean_othstudents = map_dbl(row_number(), ~ 
          mean(student_mean[-.x]))) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  class_id student_id student_mean class_mean_othstudents
  <chr>         <dbl>        <dbl>                  <dbl>
1 a                 1       0.256                  0.907 
2 a                 2       0.0999                 0.986 
3 a                 3       1.72                   0.178 
4 b                 4      -0.402                  0.195 
5 b                 5       0.0305                -0.0211
6 b                 6       0.360                 -0.186
```

Comment: I don't think this quite answers my question. Here the class_avg variable is the average of all the students in the class, rather than all the students *except* for the given student. So class_avg for student_id 1 should be the mean of student_id 2 and 3, class_avg for student 2 should be the mean of student_id 1 and 3, etc.

Comment: @jsizzle you can check the update.  I didnt understand your comment about `manual` approach with the other solution

Comment: Thanks so much, this is super helpful. My comment about a "manual" approach was in reference to @jared_mamrot (very useful!) comment. This relies on a hand calculation of the mean and is not a general solution that would easily allow a different . Your answer is more general because it allows us to call the "mean" function directly on student_mean[-.x] and calculate other statistics by calling a different function there.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the statistics you want for each classroom you could calculate them 'manually', e.g. `classroom_mean = sum(x) / n`; `classroom_mean_excluding_the_student_in_question = sum(x) - x / n - 1`

E.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  class_id = c(rep("a", 6), rep("b", 6)),
  student_id = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 2), rep(3, 1), rep(4, 2), rep(5, 3), rep(6, 1)),
  value = rnorm(12)
)

df %>% 
  group_by(class_id, student_id)  %>% 
  summarise(student_mean = mean(value)) %>% 
  mutate(class_mean_exc_this_student = (
    sum(student_mean) - student_mean)/(n() - 1)
    )
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'class_id'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   class_id [2]
#>   class_id student_id student_mean class_mean_exc_this_student
#>   <chr>         <dbl>        <dbl>                       <dbl>
#> 1 a                 1       0.256                       0.907 
#> 2 a                 2       0.0999                      0.986 
#> 3 a                 3       1.72                        0.178 
#> 4 b                 4      -0.402                       0.195 
#> 5 b                 5       0.0305                     -0.0211
#> 6 b                 6       0.360                      -0.186
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This definitely works for the "mean" case and is a clever workaround. I think is very similar to this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35858876/calculate-group-mean-while-excluding-current-observation-using-dplyr). It is not a general solution for an unspecified function. Does that exist?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which computes `student_mean` and `class_mean_othstudents` *bottom up* as *overall mean*. The result differs from the other answers posted so far which use the *mean of means* to compute `class_mean_othstudents`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(unique(student_id), 
                   \(sid) .(student_id = sid, 
                            student_mean = mean(value[student_id == sid]),
                            class_mean_othstudents = mean(value[student_id != sid]))) |>
            rbindlist(), 
          by = .(class_id)]
```

> ```
>    class_id student_id student_mean class_mean_othstudents
> 1:        a          1   0.25601839              0.6382870
> 2:        a          2   0.09989806              0.6207800
> 3:        a          3   1.71506499              0.1935703
> 4:        b          4  -0.40207251              0.1128452
> 5:        b          5   0.03052233             -0.1481104
> 6:        b          6   0.35981383             -0.1425156
> ```

---

For the sake of completeness and for comparison with the other answers here is the version which is using *means of means*:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(student_mean = mean(value)), by = .(class_id, student_id)][
  , class_student_mean := 
    .SD[, sapply(student_id, \(sid) mean(student_mean[student_id != sid])), 
        by = class_id]$V1][]
```

> ```
>    class_id student_id student_mean class_student_mean
> 1:        a          1   0.25601839         0.90748153
> 2:        a          2   0.09989806         0.98554169
> 3:        a          3   1.71506499         0.17795823
> 4:        b          4  -0.40207251         0.19516808
> 5:        b          5   0.03052233        -0.02112934
> 6:        b          6   0.35981383        -0.18577509
> ```

This result is in line with the other two answers which are based on *means of means*

#### Data

Note that the same *seed* as in [Jared's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68355107/3817004) and in OP's edit ist used.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  class_id = c(rep("a", 6), rep("b", 6)),
  student_id = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 2), rep(3, 1), rep(4, 2), rep(5, 3), rep(6, 1)),
  value = rnorm(12)
)
```